# Is it possible to push my code from my server to Github?

Tags: git, github, push

I used **Github** a few months ago but only between my computer to **Github**. What I want to be able to do now is to push the code from my **server** to **Github**. The reason for this is because I work differently now. I currently saving my code directly to my **server** provided by my hosting provider.

**Is it possible to push my code from my server to Github?**

*Also I should mention that I currently only have FTP access to my server and use **FileZilla** to connect.*

**UPDATE**

I went to **#git IRC** channel and found out from some people there that it is impossible to use git with out the ability to SSH from one's server. I have contacted my host to see if I can SSH from the server and install git there?

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways of doing this.

1. If you have access to your server with a command shell (or remote desktop, or whatever) you can simply init a git repository there.
2. If you have ftp access, you can map your ftp as a drive with something like NetDrive ([this article explains that](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/map-your-ftp-drive-as-a-local-drive-with-netdrive-windows-only/)), and then use the same method you usually do, but with your mapped drive

On another note I'd say a better option is to do it differently: Work locally, and write a script which updates your web code when you commit something. Would that be an option?

Comment: Why not just clone from the server, then push to Github?

Comment: @larsmans: Because developing live on the server is rarely the best solution. Set this up like this now, write a script to pull from git and build. Later on it would be trivial to add automated testing or something like that, or pushing to another/multiple servers.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what is the Linux equivalent of Net Drive is?

Comment: I'd say you could simply use git over ssh if you're working on linux, or am I missing a piece of the puzzle here?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to your host provider server, I suggest setting up a post-receive hook.

I assume your server has permission to push to your github repo, otherwise, follow the [official GitHub documentation](http://help.github.com/key-setup-redirect) first.

On your server, create `<path-to-repo>/hooks/post-receive`, containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Pushing $3 $1 to github."
git push github $3
```

Give it permission to execute:

```
chmod +x <path-to-repo>/hooks/post-receive
```

Add `github` as a remote repository:

```
cd <path-to-repo>
git add remote github git@github.com:<username>/<repo-name>.git
```

Then every push to your server will make it push to the configured github repository.

Answer (score 2):

In GitHub, upload your servers "public" ssh key (under accounts options).

In your server, can you clone your GitHub repo, and just copy your server data to that repo, and then push? That way, GitHub is now updated with your server copy. Now you can develop on your server, or at your personal computer since both are repositories cloned from GitHub.

If what your doing is for production (goes to live directly), I would recommend having some sort of script to publish your results instead of developing on the live server directly.

My workflow is the following:

1. Clone GitHub project to my home.
2. Create two branches, master branch and production branch on GitHub.
3. Create a Git Hook, when stuff being pushed to production branch, it will deploy the contents to the server automatically.
4. I continue development on the master branch, and when it is release time, I just merge it to the production branch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. You'd have to write an app to interact with the git command-line...but you should be able to push code from anywhere to github.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

You need to have your SSH-key available somehow. You can either copy it to the server, or enable agent-forwarding --- e.g. by doing "ssh -A ...". Read up on the latter here - http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html